# TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

```
var crud = angular.module('Crud', ['ngRoute']);

crud.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/edit/:index', {
        templateUrl: 'js/views/edit.html',
        controller: 'EditCtrl'
    }).when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'js/views/list.html'
    })
}]);

crud.controller('EditCtrl',['$scope', function(scope,$routeParams){
    scope.name = scope.names[$routeParams.index];
}]);
```

Why am i getting index undefined. My url seems to be fine, `http://localhost:63342/Angular-CRUD/#/edit/2` It seems that id is passing correctly from view, but why am i `getting index` undefined in my controller.

Comment: On which line does this error occur?

Comment: scope.name = scope.names[$routeParams.index]; on this line.

Comment: It's not `index` that's `undefined`, it's the object from which you're trying to access `index` that is `undefined`, which would be `$routeParams` (from the expression `$routeParams.index`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not passed `$routeParams` in dependency

```
                                     //here
crud.controller('EditCtrl',['$scope','$routeParams', function(scope,$routeParams){
    scope.name = scope.names[$routeParams.index];
}]);
```